# paypal options required field

Tags: paypal, required

I'm using Paypal with some Option fields like below:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="note" />
<input type="text" name="os0" />
```

Is it possible to make this a required field? I know Paypal has it's own required fields to be passed.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
<input type="text" name="os0" required />
```

HTML5 takes care of the validation for you.

But support is not guaranteed: http://caniuse.com/forms

A better solution would be to use something like the [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin.